# IOS Newsstand app with no subscription

Tags: ios

Is it possible to create a newsstand app with all issues as free?.

Can any one help me out with a step-by-step guide for essentials concerning the creation of newsstand app and submitting it to the app store?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a magazine with all free issues but it's necessary to provide user with a free subscription (Free Subscription In-App Purchase).

IMO best Newsstand tutorial is from [Viggio Soft](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/).

Submitting is just like any other app, just remember to enable Newsstand in iTC.